# Relinux ISO networking issue

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, internet, relinux

I am trying to make bootable ISO of my Ubuntu 14.04. I used relinux and generated iso file. After booting live system i can not access the Internet. I can connect to the network but no Internet access. In terminal i can ping 8.8.8.8 but www.google.com does not work.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Relinux from the launchpad site ?
The author recommends against using the latest version, however I use Relinux 0.4a1 and have done for the past couple of years without problems.

I encountered the problem you describe in an earlier version of Relinux.I am typing this comment on an Lubuntu 16.04 Relinux created usb created two days ago :)

Comment: I am using https://launchpad.net/relinux/0.3/0.3.0a2/+download/relinux_0.3.0a2.tar.gz. I solved my issue by adding: cd /etc
sudo ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf